# PHP Session from my site or from Facebook (or some other integration)

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-php-sdk

I hope this is simple. I am working on a site where a user can register directly with the site or sign in with Facebook etc. What I want to know is how to handle the session data at the top of the script?

Here is what I have:

`if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 'true') {
}`

I have tried:

`if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 'true')|| if $user{`

But this is throwing out an error: unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR

Is this even the right way of doing this kind of session work? Or should I be approaching this differently? Has anybody else done this that they would be willing to share?

Thanks,

Lewis

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax is NOT

```
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 'true')|| if $user{...}
```

it is...

```
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 'true' || $condition2==true){...}
```

All of your conditions in their logical order must be contained in the if's parantheses. Since `if` statements always check for true, so this can be simplified like so

```
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] || $condition2){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's basic PHP syntax:

```
if (($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 'true') || ($user whatever....)) {
    ...
}
```